# How to use Nuget Package- Recaptcha control in C# code- .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I have successfully added the Recaptcha dll reference using Nuget Package manager in Visual Studio 2012.

How can I add this in to the web part control? I have added a simple label in to my project. How can I add my Recaptcha control as below?

```
Label validationLabel = new Label();
this.Controls.Add(validationLabel);
```

Answer (score 2):

The details on how to use a Recaptcha control are on the [Recaptcha Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet).

Basically, this is how you do it:

Add this to the top of the page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>
```

Then use the control in your webpart like this:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
    ID="recaptcha"
    runat="server"
    PublicKey="your_public_key"
    PrivateKey="your_private_key"
    />
```

To place this control on the WebPart from the .cs file, you can do something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
        return;

    RecaptchaControl rc = new RecaptchaControl { PublicKey = "6LcvP...", PrivateKey = "6LcvP..." };
    this.Controls.Add(rc);
}
```

Since Sharepoint WebParts are ASP.NET controls, you can dynamically add controls as you wish. Handling them on PostBack could be a bit of a bother, but there's a lot of resources on this subject all over the net, including on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375276/dynamically-add-links-to-sharepoint-webpart) [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback).
You should go through the Recaptcha documentation to see all the properties you can use.

Comment: thanks for d answer.im using recaptcha dll in nuget manager. i need to insert in to a .cs file not to the markup file.i need to use using statement and add the control to the .cs page since im adding a web part.

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. Check it out, see if it helps.